# Is it possible to add incrementing id number to IntelliJ-IDEA run executions?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to add incrementing id number to IntelliJ-IDEA run executions?   I want a unique env variable to increment by one each time I run a test execution.   Sorta like how Jenkins keeps track of build# .

Comment: Did you try `System.setProperty(...)` etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct support for this feature in IDEA, so you'll have to code something yourself. However, in the run/debug configurations there is an option to perform various actions before running. So you could, for example, write a gradle task to increment a build number and have IDEA run this task each time you execute your app.

If you add this to the defaults then it will get picked up for all your run configurations and you won't have to remember to add it in each time.